# What does ぶわははは mean?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I am participating in online chats to improve my Japanese, and occasionally receive chat words or expressions that I do not understand. Thank you.

Comment: I was marked down on this post, but I am noｗ aware of the term Bwahahaha as I have not seen this term in English!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It represents (somewhat of) a deep, bellowed laughter.  `Bwahahaha`